A poor guy who wove fabric to make a living, a bird decides to help
A man who wove fabrics in his little beat-up house in a village. There were white birds all around in that area. This one time A stranger lady knocks on his door thirsty, he brings her in and gives her water, and the room to sleep in for the night. 
Next day lady tells him to do his chores and she will weave the fabric. The guy comes back in the evening to find out the much longer piece of cloth and none of the thread was used. He was amazed and upon asking the lady replied that he should never ask this and whenever she is working, he should never enter the room.
Things went to normal, guy was making good progress by selling more cloth created without any raw material. One day, he couldn't take his curiosity anymore, and decides to take a peak. He opens the door, and bam! it was a Bird (one of the kinds found outside) who was picking her feathers and weaving the fabric. He got astonished and goes back outside, then the lady comes from the room and gives him the piece of fabric and tells him that this was the last one, her cover is blown now she has to leave. She walks out through that door. The man filled with regrets runs outside only to find Birds flying. He shouted and no one replied.

Sounds like Japanese folkltale The Crane Wife (which was adapted to a stop-motion short in 1977). Here's a related (though not identical) question.

Agree with @Walt. It's a folktale I remember reading/hearing in my childhood.

Tsuru (1988)
IMDb's Plot Summary:

Based on the folk tales "Repayment from a crane". One snowy night a beautiful woman named Tsuru (Crane) visits poor peasant Taiju sand says she will become his wife... 

Our Facebook group found this movie which sounds similar.

This is exactly what I was looking for. Is there any place I can find english subtitles?
